# How to use Like Operator during update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these type of docnos (BP/2016/00344,BP/2016/00345,BP/2016/00346) and  (CP/2016/00344,CP/2016/00345,CP/2016/00346)

like that i have more than 100 records,now my task is to change the year to 2015 instead of 2016 by one update query

pls help me

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to use a like?  I would think like could result in improper records being updated.

It appears year is always in positions 4-7. If this is true, using string functions this task becomes pretty straight forward.

I suggest the following approach over using a replace function because your trailing numbers in your string of 00345 may reach 2015 and I don't think you'd want to replace them.

So 
UNTESTED:

```
update table 
set docnos = left(Docnos,3)+'2016'+right(Docnos,len(docnos)-7)
where substring(docnos,4,4) = '2015'
```

- Why minus 7?  (3 for ZZ/, 4 more for the year totaling 7)
- Why use a
  where clause? becuase you indicated you only wanted to update the
  2015 records.

Assumptions.

1. First 3 positions will ALWAYS Be  in format `ZZ/` where zz could be any 2 values
2. Positions 4-7 are the year you need to evaluate

Now if you must use a like...

I Suppose
we could change our where to be `where docNo like '%/2015/%'`

Comment: I like this solution; it seems much safer than a generic replace.  However, you could simplify the code using `stuff()`.

Comment: always value you input

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE Table
SET docnos = REPLACE(docnos,'/2015/','/2016/')
```

This should work as well.

Also, like xQbert said, if LIKE is a must use you can add in `where docnos like '%/2015/%'`

Comment: Nice! I should have evaluated the / as part of the replace. instead of omitting use of replace.

Answer (score 3):

This is an elaboration on xQbert's approach.  Assuming that the year always starts on 4th character, then you can do:

```
update t
    set docno = stuff(docno, 7, 1, '6')
    where docno like '__/2015/%';
```

Comment: thanks jordan,finally its updated with single query   i used this update ReceiptsAndPayments set DocNo=STUFF(r.DocNo,7,1,'5') from ReceiptsAndPayments r where DocNo like '%2016%'